# c# webbrowser not updating/inserting

Tags: c#, html

Neither of these methods are working for me and for the life of me I can't figure out why.  Been googling like crazy and prowling this site, which is where I found the commented method below.

No matter what I do, the content displayed is NOT updating :'(

ANY help would be appreciated.. I'm at my wits' end.

```
        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string docText =
            "<html><!DOCTYPE html>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "<style type=\"text/css\"> #footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; height: 0px; } </style>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + Environment.NewLine +
            "function appendHtml(o) {" + Environment.NewLine +
            "var div = document.createElement(\"div\");" + Environment.NewLine +
            "div.innerHTML = o;" + Environment.NewLine +
            "document.body.appendChild(div);" + Environment.NewLine +
            "}" + Environment.NewLine +
            "</script>" + Environment.NewLine + "<body>" + Environment.NewLine + "</body></html>" +
            //"<body></body>" + 
            //"<table align=\"center\" border=\"0px\" id=\"footer\" width=\"100%\"></table>" + 
            Environment.NewLine;


        msgLog.DocumentText = docText;
        Application.DoEvents();

        HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();
        table.Width = "100%";

        HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();
        tr.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell("shit"));
        tr.Cells[0].Width = "100%";

        table.Rows.Add(tr);

        InsertHtmlControl(table, msgLog);

    }

    public static void InsertHtmlControl(HtmlControl c, WebBrowser wb)
    {

        // create a HtmlTextWriter;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter htmlw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        // render the control as html
        c.RenderControl(htmlw);

        ////invoke the script passing in the html 
        //object[] p = new object[1];
        //p[0] = (object)sb.ToString();

        //Trace.WriteLine("Invoking: " + sb.ToString());

        //wb.Document.InvokeScript("appendHtml", p);

        HtmlElement body = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        body.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();

        wb.Update();

        htmlw.Close();
        htmlw.Dispose();

        sw.Dispose();


    }
```

Comment: Move all your codes after `msgLog.DocumentText = docText;` to *DocumentCompleted* event

Comment: @I4V: Did as suggested and still no changes appear.  Moved everything starting with `HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();` and on into `msgLog_DocumentCompleted`. Still getting nada. :(
Edit: Apparently it IS changing, though it's not reflected when "Viewing Source".  However the table formatting isn't keeping. (ie; it's stripping out all html and just inserting the text)